# Simple IRA Non-elective Contributions and Maximum 401k Employee contributions?

Tags: united-states, taxes, retirement-plan, simple-ira

Person is an employee and is self-employed.  Person has maxed out annual 401k contributions at employer's company. Can this person receive Simple IRA 2% annual nonelective contributions from second place of employment in which he's a self-employed owner?

Answer (score 1):

If you maxed out your 401k, you cannot make any *elective* contributions to the Simple IRA. Non-elective are not counted towards that limit, so you can still have the non-elective contributions made for you (similar to the 401k match).

Read more [here](http://www.irs.gov/Retirement-Plans/Plan-Participant,-Employee/Retirement-Topics-SIMPLE-IRA-Contribution-Limits).

Check with a professional tax adviser (EA/CPA licensed in your State) what would be the requirements for the owner to be eligible for the non-elective contribution.

Comment: Thanks why would it be different eligibility for an owner to receive a non-elective contribution vs an employee in the 2nd company?

Comment: @peach12 there are some restrictions on owners with regards to the retirement plans, so I suggest talking to someone who is well versed in all these rules.